# Drawing geometry in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

Taking the standard opengl 4.0+ functions & specifications into consideration; i've seen that geometries and shapes can be created in either two ways:

> 1. making use of VAO & VBO s.
> 2. using shader programs.

which one is the standard way of creating shapes?? are they consistent with each other?  or they are two different ways for creating geometry and shapes?

Comment: Geometry shaders can be used to modify geometry (e.g. [level of detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail)) on the hardware but they still need input data to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geometry is loaded into the GPU with  VAO & VBO.

- [Geometry shaders](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) produce new geometry based on uploaded. Use them to make special effects like particles, shadows([Shadow Volumes](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch11.html)) in more efficient way.
- [tessellation shaders](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/glsl-core-tutorial-tessellation/) serve to subdivide geometry for some effects like [displacement mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping).

*I strongly (like really strongly) recommend you reading this http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-index/*

Comment: thanks for your answer and reference, well so far i've used shaders for creating shapes, so you mean the real deal is with VAO and VBO?? so far i've created shapes with shaders, are these shapes some sort of dummy simulated shapes??

Comment: It will be better if you will not think about using Geometry shaders before reading about them. If you need to draw something on screen - just upload and draw it damn it :) But to your question: geometry which was produced by Geometry shaders stored in the GPU memory and injected to the GPU pipeline. Main advantage is thay you can instantly produce large amount of geometry in parallel way by GPU cores and it doesn't require uploading of large amount of data to the GPU(PC bus is  bottleneck)

Comment: @BulBul *"so far i've used shaders for creating shapes"* - No you haven't, believe me. What you did was draw geometry from VAOs and VBOs using shaders, this is not exclusive, you always need a VAO and VBO to upload any geometry, no matter if you change this geometry using any shaders.

Answer (score 4):

VAOs and VBOs how about what geometry to draw (specifying per-vertex data). Shader programs are about how to draw them (which program gets applied to each provided vertex, each fragment and so on).

Answer (score 3):

Let's lay out the full facts.

Shaders need input. Without input that changes, every shader invocation will produce exactly the same values. That's how shaders work. When you issue a draw call, a number of shader invocations are launched. The *only variables* that will change from invocation to invocation within this draw call are `in` variables. So unless you use some sort of input, every shader will produce the same outputs.

*However*, that doesn't mean you absolutely need a VAO that actually contains things. It is perfectly legal (though there are some drivers that don't support it) to render with a VAO that doesn't have [*any* attributes enabled](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) (though you have to use array rendering, not indexed rendering). In which case, all user-defined inputs to the vertex shader (if any) will be filled in [with context state](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Non-array_attribute_values), which will be constant.

The vertex shader does have some other, built-in per-vertex inputs generated by the system. [Namely gl_VertexID](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs). This is the index used by OpenGL to uniquely identify this particular vertex. It will be different for every vertex.

So you could, for example, fetch geometry data yourself based on this index through uniform buffers, buffer textures, or some other mechanism. Or you can procedurally generate vertex data based on the index. Or something else. You could pass that data along to tessellation shaders for them to tessellate the generated data. Or to geometry shaders to do whatever it is you want with those. However you want to turn that index into real data is up to you.

[Here's an example from my tutorial series that generates vertex data from nothing more than an index](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tutorial%2013.html).

Answer (score 2):

> i've seen that geometries and shapes can be created in either two ways:

Not either. In modern OpenGL-4 you need both data and programs.

VBOs and VAOs do contain the raw geometry data. Shaders are the programs (usually executed on the GPU) that turn the raw data into pixels on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Vertex shaders can be used to displace vertices, or to generate them from a builtin formula and the vertex index, which is available as a built in attribute in later open gl versions.

The difference between vertex and geometry shaders is that vertex shader is a 1:1 mapping, while geometry shader can create more vertices -- can be utilized in automatic Level of Detail generation for e.g. NURBS or perlin noise based terrains etc.